# Call WebView#getDrawingCache() asynchrnously without freezing UI thread

Tags: android, android-webview

I'm trying to grab the screenshot of a WebView, however, WebView#getDrawingCache(true) is an expensive call and freezes the UI thread.

Nevertheless, any attempt to move this to an AsyncTask or a separate thread, will result in a "All WebView methods must be called on the UI thread" error.

Is there a workaround for this, such that I can work on WebView#getDrawingCache(true) in a background thread without freezing the UI thread?

Here's a some code example that crashes

```
public class TouchTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, Void> {
    Runnable completionCallback;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Object... objects) {
        Integer id = (Integer) objects[0];
        completionCallback = (Runnable) objects[1];
        touch(id);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void res) {
        super.onPostExecute(res);
        completionCallback.run();
    }
}

/*
Updates the webview's bitmap in cache
 */
public Pair<String, Bitmap> touch(Integer id) {
    CustomWebView webView = getWebView(id);
    String title = webView.getTitle();
    Bitmap screenie = getScreenshotFromWebView(webView);

    Pair<String, Bitmap> res = new Pair<String, Bitmap>(title, screenie);
    bitmapCache.put(id, res);
    return res;
}

public void touchAsync(Integer id, Runnable callback) {
    new TouchTask().execute(id, callback);
}

public Bitmap getScreenshotFromWebView(WebView webView) {
    webView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    webView.buildDrawingCache(true);
    Bitmap screenieBitmap = null;
    if ((webView.getDrawingCache(true) != null) && (!webView.getDrawingCache(true).isRecycled())) {
        screenieBitmap = webView.getDrawingCache(false);
        screenieBitmap = compressScreenshot(webView.getDrawingCache(false));
    }
    return screenieBitmap;
}

public Bitmap compressScreenshot(Bitmap screenie) {
    Display display = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    int width = size.x;
    int height = size.y;
    return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(screenie, width / 3, height / 3, true);
}
```

And here's the running code:

```
new TouchTask().execute(id, callback);
```

And here's the error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.Throwable: A WebView method was called on thread 'AsyncTask #3'. All WebView methods must be called on the same thread. (Expected Looper Looper (main, tid 1) {16dba051} called on null, FYI main Looper is Looper (main, tid 1) {16dba051})
            at android.webkit.WebView.checkThread(WebView.java:2185)
            at android.webkit.WebView.getTitle(WebView.java:1321)
            at com.nubelacorp.javelin.activities.helpers.browseractivity.TabManager.touch(TabManager.java:53)
            at com.nubelacorp.javelin.activities.helpers.browseractivity.TabManager$TouchTask.doInBackground(TabManager.java:145)
            at com.nubelacorp.javelin.activities.helpers.browseractivity.TabManager$TouchTask.doInBackground(TabManager.java:138)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
     Caused by: java.lang.Throwable: A WebView method was called on thread 'AsyncTask #3'. All WebView methods must be called on the same thread. (Expected Looper Looper (main, tid 1) {16dba051} called on null, FYI main Looper is Looper (main, tid 1) {16dba051})
            at android.webkit.WebView.checkThread(WebView.java:2175)
            at android.webkit.WebView.getTitle(WebView.java:1321)
            at com.nubelacorp.javelin.activities.helpers.browseractivity.TabManager.touch(TabManager.java:53)
            at com.nubelacorp.javelin.activities.helpers.browseractivity.TabManager$TouchTask.doInBackground(TabManager.java:145)
            at com.nubelacorp.javelin.activities.helpers.browseractivity.TabManager$TouchTask.doInBackground(TabManager.java:138)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: you can call getDrawingCache(true) in non UI thread

Comment: @pskink are you sure? i believe i tried it and i got an error

Comment: and i tried and i didn't get an error

Comment: @pskink can you show the code that you worked with? i've updated my question with an asynctask sample code that crashes.

Comment: it was just good, old Thread with overriden run() method...

Comment: @pskink do you have any Activity#runOnUiThread() ?

Comment: definitely did not work, even with just regular threads.

Comment: that worked for me: http://pastebin.com/UTUS9rUR v2.2, seems they added some other checks, maybe in v4.0+

Comment: @pskink what version of android are you on? i'm on android L. i know it worked in older versions but it fails with an error in 4.4+

Answer (score 5):

To obtain a screenshot off a background thread, you'll have to use a different method.

We'll create a `Canvas` backed by a `Bitmap` and then ask the `WebView`, or the container holding the `WebView`(will discuss why you would need this later), to draw *itself* on this canvas. At the end, the `Bitmap` used by the `Canvas` will hold the required screenshot. It can then be flushed to storage.

I have modified your `AsyncTask` to represent the bare-bone implementation. Currently, it only shows that the `Bitmap` is being generated inside the `doInBackground(...)` method - off the main thread.

```
public class TouchTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, Bitmap> {

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Object... objects) {
        // Create a new Bitmap with dimensions of the WebView
        Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(webView.getWidth(), 
                            webView.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        // Canvas that is backed by the `Bitmap` and used by webView to draw on
        Canvas c = new Canvas(b);

        // WebView draws itself
        webView.draw(c);

        // Return bitmap
        // OR: Compress the bitmap here itself
        // No need to do that in `onPostExecute(...)`
        return b;
    }

    // There's no need to actually do anything inside `onPostExecute(..)`
    // Compressing and saving the bitmap to sdcard can be handled
    // in `doInBackground(...)` itself
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        super.onPostExecute(bitmap);

        if (bitmap != null) {
            FileOutputStream fos;
            try {
                fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("/sdcard/webview_screenshot.png"));
                bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

While testing, I also found that this method takes less time than using `getDrawingCache()`. I haven't tried to find the reason yet.

**`...or the container holding the WebView(will discuss why you would need this later)...`**

Consider the scenario when the `WebView` is scrolled. If you use the method described above, the screenshot obtained *will not* be accurate - the screenshot will show the `WebView` as if the scroll was `0` - aligned top & left. To capture the `WebView` even in the scrolled state, place it inside a container - say `Framelayout`. The process remains similar, except for the following changes: we will use the `FrameLayout's` width and height when creating the Bitmap:

```
Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(frameLayout.getWidth(), 
                            frameLayout.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
```

Instead of asking the `WebView`, we'll ask the `FrameLayout` to draw itself:

```
frameLayout.draw(c);
```

And that should do it.

Comment: this actually still does not work (on android L).

Here's the exception:      Caused by: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

Comment: @nubela I'll give this a try myself later on. Another suggestion: have you tried to benchmark this vs `getDrawingCache` _on the main thread_? I had seen that the `canvas` method works quite fast - your ui thread will not held for long. I'll get back to you.

Comment: not yet on main thread, but i'll give this a roll. i find this webview main-thread only limitation extremely silly. i have to freeze the UI everytime i wanna do anything with draw.

Comment: @Vikram, the example you have given worked but the screenshot is just blank filled with black colour. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

It depends if you are trying to take a single capture, or a continuous capture stream.
In both cases, the screen capture and the bitmap storing will be done in a background thread to avoid freezing the Android main Thread.

The first AsyncTask can be used to take and save a single screenshot:

```
public class SingleScreenshotTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap> {
    View view;
    Context context;

    public SingleScreenshotTask(View view) {
        this.view = view;
        this.context = this.view.getContext().getApplicationContext();
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        view.draw(canvas);
        saveBitmap(context, bitmap);
        return bitmap;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // do something more on the UI thread?
    }

}
```

The second can be used to continuously save screenshots: (See how the Bitmap and Canvas are re-used for memory efficiency)

```
public class ContinuousScreenshotTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Bitmap, Void> {
    View view;
    Context context;
    Bitmap bitmap;
    Canvas canvas;

    public ContinuousScreenshotTask(View view) {
        this.view = view;
        this.context = this.view.getContext().getApplicationContext();
        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        while (!isCancelled()) {
            try {
                // some timeout to avoid cpu overload
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                return null;
            }
            view.draw(canvas);
            saveBitmap(context, bitmap);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Bitmap... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        // do something more on the UI thread?
    }
}
```

Both AsyncTask are using this method to save the Bitmap to internal storage:

```
public static void saveBitmap(Context context, Bitmap bitmap) {
    FileOutputStream out;
    try {
        out = context.openFileOutput(System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

To execute these tasks, you can do the following:

```
View yourViewToCapture;
new ScreenShotTask(yourViewToCapture).execute();
```

or

```
View yourViewToCapture;
ContinuousScreenshotTask continuousScreenShotTask;

public void toggle() {
    if (continuousScreenShotTask == null) {
        continuousScreenShotTask = new ContinuousScreenshotTask(webview);
        continuousScreenShotTask.execute();
    } else {
        continuousScreenShotTask.cancel(true);
        continuousScreenShotTask = null;
    }
}
```